# PyQt6. Всем привет. Как ввести и сохранить в программе числа?

Tags: python

Я хочу что-то похожее на QLabel. Чтобы выглядело как QLabel, но что бы я могла вводить и сохранять числа, а не текст,  в какую-нибудь переменную. Или способ переделать полученный текст из QLabel в число, без кучи лишних строк. Я уже долго ищу,но внятного и достаточно понятного ответа нигде не вижу.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не очень понятен. Пожалуйста, покажите ваш код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `str` для того чтобы перевести число в строку и `int` для того чтобы перевести строку в число:

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 700, 400)

        label = QLabel(self)

        label.setText(str(123))
        print(int(label.text()))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```